# Combining selenium with facebook api and making request

Tags: facebook, selenium, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I have 3 questions: 1)Can I combine facebook login via mozila browser(selenium) with facebook graph api, for example:

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://facebook.com')
user=browser.find_element_by_id('email')
user.send_keys('email')
password=browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
password.send_keys('pass')
login=browser.find_element_by_id('u_0_r')
login.click()
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")

friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]

print (friend_list)
```

2)Can somebody help me with login on facebook  through app_id, secret_id and token, or through email and password
3)I want to get profile info, for example with help of get_object, but I need to know user's id to do it. How can I get this id, if I have only page url's, or I can use part after facebook.com/ to do this request?
P.s. If u know answer at least on one of this questions, pls right it in comments or in answers, it will be very useful:)

Comment: 1) Scraping Facebook is not allowed. 2) Is not allowed. 3) You get the User ID when the user uses Facebook Login in your app

Comment: I don't  want to scrap "not allowed" data. I want to combine login via mozila and graph.get_object request  to get public_profile data

Comment: Facebook Terms of Service and Facebook Platform Policy say you are not allowed to do that. You are not allowed to login using automated ways